# javascript function not taking arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This question is probably more complex than I realize.

When the page loads, it checks for a cookie (usercookie). If it exists, it calls a function in an external .js file. This function is situated in a jquery file and does three things. It hides come stuff, sets a variable (userloggedin) to true, and displays a welcome message to the users. However, its acting very strange. In order for the function to work, I have to define it with a "new" before it like its an object. If I don't do that, it won't work at all. But if I use it, it refuses to take any arguments. Take a look.

Keep in mind that this is situated in a $(document).ready(function() {}

```
userlogged = new function($name) 
 {
    userloggedin = true;
    $('.socialicons').hide();
    $('#signup').hide();
    $('#login').hide();
     document.getElementById('cookieelement').innerHTML = "Welcome back, " + $name + "!";
}
```

Here is how I call the function from the main document.

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="cookiescript">
//checks for the usercookie and gets the value as well
var query = true;
if (query === true) 
{

cookievalue = 
"Seth";
userlogged(cookievalue);
}

</script>
```

Some of this code was returned from a php query to mysql, but I know that code works fine.

So my question is, how do I create this universal function in the js file that I can call anytime a user logs in somehow (eg. cookie detected, form entry)?

Answer (score 3):

You have to declare a parameter at the declaration part like
`function functionname(parameter)`

Comment: parameter in this case being $name

Comment: sorry, I was playing around with the code before I posted the question, it doesn't work with the parameter in the declaration either

Comment: Make the declaration part like this: `function userlogged($value)` so in the function body (`{ ... }`) you can use the `$value` if it's passed. Example of use: `userlogged(2);` In this case `$value` equals to `2`. I think I cannot be more specific. Good luck with that.

Answer (score 1):

you need to change the method signature to accept a parameter

```
userlogged = new function($name)
 {
    userloggedin = true;
    $('.socialicons').hide();
    $('#signup').hide();
    $('#login').hide();
     document.getElementById('cookieelement').innerHTML = "Welcome back, " + $name + "!";
}
```